# Layout Configurations Android - API Levels

Tags: android, android-layout, resources, screen, dpi

I am struggling to define resources for certain types of screens. The main screens I am focusing on are:

Galaxy Ace  (320x480 mdpi)
Galaxy S2   (480x800 hdpi)

My questions are:

Can you define a layout for 3.2+ as: layout-sw320dp-mdpi AND drawable-sw320dp-mdpi?

If so, how do you define between the Galaxy Ace and S2 for anything lower than Android 3.2? 
As both screens are classed as 'normal' would it be layout-normal-mdpi for the Ace and layout-normal-hpdi for the S2?

**EDIT:**

Under testing on the emulator (API 4.0) the Galaxy Ace 320x480 decided to use the layout-sw320dp-hdpi resources rather than the layout-sw320dp-mdpi?? Very confusing!

Comment: Having layouts based upon screen density is a code smell. IMHO, both the Galaxy Ace and the Galaxy S2 should use the same layouts, as they are the same basic screen size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Galaxy S2** - 4.3'' , 480 * 800, 240 dpi

**Galaxy Ace**- 3.5'', 320 * 480, 164dpi

Classifying devices as per Official Android guidelines as given [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) :

**Galaxy Ace**: normal - mdpi

**Galaxy S2**: normal - hdpi

Therefore, using `layout-normal-mdpi` for the Ace and `layout-normal-hdpi` for the S2 would work fine !